# How to open MobaXTerm terminal in VSCode?

Tags: linux, remote, visual-studio-code, mobaxterm

Hi All I am using a Windows 10 machine ,for my Work I connect to a linux server using MobaxTerm  ,For I my Work currently I modify  my files using Notepad++ then i deploy the File to Linux server using Filezilla and then I compile my File using MobaXterm on Linux Server,
So Now I have started using Visual Studio Code as my editor 
I wanted to know is there any way to transfer and compile  my files to linux server 
with only  using VsCode ?

Note: I cannot change any settings on Linux server

Comment: Why do you use another terminal emulator? VSCode it self has integrated terminal which can be connected to remote server. See this https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/remote-overview

Comment: You want to be able to x11 forwarding without any other configs or apps. 
MobaXTerm terminal, give you that.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can Use `Winscp` and set path of `Vscode.exe` into the editors of `Winscp`
2. From `VSCode` install Remote `SSH` extension and add the configuration of your Linux Server into the `SSH` config file.